# Wordpress order taxonomies alphabetically

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I have the following query:

```
<?php 
$args = array(
    'hide_empty' => false, 
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'DESC' 
);
$terms = get_terms( 'projets-location', $args );
 if ( !empty( $terms ) && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
     foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>   

        <h5 id="<?php echo $term->slug; ?>" class="filter-menu-item" data-filter=".<?php echo $term->slug; ?>">
            <strong><?php echo $term->name; ?></strong>
        </h5>

    <?php }
 } ?>
```

which shows all the taxonomy terms from the projets-location taxonomy, I've added the orderby and order attributes above but STILL they're not displaying in alphabetical order at all, am I being stupid her or is there something I'm going wrong? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should use **'orderby' => 'name'**

Comment: @user1374796, I've tested it, it works for me. Both variants 'orderby' => 'name' and 'orderby' => 'title' works correct. Can you show the list of term names, which you get as the result of your code processing?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue recently with some older taxonomies. Some had been parents and others had been children. I'm not sure if that affected the outcome, but I ultimately discovered a key in my `termmeta` table which I was able to remove and then everything worked like a charm. To be clear, you do need to use `'orderby' => 'name'` as mentioned in Kulikov's answer.

Once I ran this query through my DB (assuming your db prefix is `wp_`) everything displayed alphabetically as expected:

```
DELETE FROM `wp_termmeta` WHERE `wp_termmeta`.`meta_key` = 'order'
```